# Automatic windowing of the image in matlab

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, matlab-guide

I know  possibility of imcontrast and imadjust. But maybe there is another solution... ? 
I have a question concerning automatic windowing of the Image in matlab ?
Is there any possibility to perform automatic windowing ?

I would be appreciate for any help/ advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few more methods for "automatic windowing Image in Matlab".
Some applies grayscale images, and some support color.

There are linear processing algorithms like `imcontrast` and `imadjust` (linear with gamma).

There is `histeq`, that performs histogram equalization.

I can recommend `adapthisteq` that applies "Contrast-limited adaptive histogram equalization (CLAHE)"

Refer to Matalb documentation:
http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/functionlist.html#btdrtx1

> Contrast Adjustment
>
> Contrast adjustment, histogram equalization, decorrelation stretching
> Functions
>
> imadjust   Adjust image intensity values or colormap
> imcontrast  Adjust Contrast tool
> imsharpen   Sharpen image using unsharp masking
> histeq  Enhance contrast using histogram equalization
> adapthisteq Contrast-limited adaptive histogram equalization (CLAHE)
> imhistmatch Adjust histogram of image to match N-bin histogram of reference image
> decorrstretch   Apply decorrelation stretch to multichannel image
> stretchlim  Find limits to contrast stretch image
> intlut  Convert integer values using lookup table
> imnoise Add noise to image

Choosing the right method depends on your goals.
If you need fidelity to input, choose linear method.
If you need the highest contrast choose histogram equalization (in price of saturation).
If you need nice balanced image you can choose CLAHE.

The best algorithms are not built in to Matlab, but need more effort (to search, to implement, to buy...).